# Disable a form on page load and enable on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a form and I want to disable all its when I first get into it or rather on page load. I want to enable it after I clicked a button. I am using html, and angular.

```
<form name="form" id="form">
 <input type="text">
</form>
 <button type="button">Enable Form</button>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You mean you want to disable all it's contents?

Comment: @AravindhGopi yes, and then after i click a button it will enable

Comment: show us what you've tried and not working.

Answer (score 1):

Type 1: Just put `disabled` in every html form elements to disable.

and when button clicks enable them.

```js
function init(){
  var formArray = document.getElementById("myform");
  
  formArray.forEach(function(elements){
  console.log(formArray.elements[0].value);
  });
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
<form id="myform" name="myform">
<input type="text" id="myText" value="123">
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<input type="radio" id="radio">
<select disabled id="select"><option></option></select>

</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Enable Form</button>
<body>
```

Type 2: Using Jquery

```js
 function myFunction(){
  $("#form :input").prop("disabled", false);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" name="form">
<input type="text" id="myText" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" disabled>
<input type="radio" id="radio" disabled>
<select disabled id="select"><option></option></select>

</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Enable Form</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/jyzx82ws/1/

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input type="text" />
<br><br>
<select name="s1">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no">No
```

Enable Form

```
function disableForm(){
 var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
 var elements = form.elements;
 for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
  elements[i].disabled = true;
 }
}
disableForm();
document.getElementById("enbleForm").addEventListener("click", enableFrm);

function enableFrm(){
 var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
 var elements = form.elements;
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
 elements[i].disabled = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do the following**

```
<form name="form" id="form" style='display:none'>
......
</form
<button type="button" onclick="show()">Enable Form</button>
<script> 
       function show() 
            {           
             document.getElementById('form').style.display="block";
            }
</script>
```